# Read file properties using Spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations

I'm trying to learn how to read properties file using spring. After an internet searching I found that I can use `@value` and `@PropertySource` annotations to achieve that. I created a project which has the following structure and classes codes:

**Structure of the project:**

[image]

**AppConfigMongoDB.java implementation:**

```
package com.mongodb.properties;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;


@PropertySource("classpath:config/config.properties")
public class AppConfigMongoDB {

@Value("#{mongodb.url}")
private String mongodbUrl;


@Value("#{mongodb.db}")
private String defaultDb;

public String getMongoDb()
{
    return defaultDb;
}

public String getMongoDbUrl()
{
    return mongodbUrl;
}
}
```

**SpringConfiguration.java implementation:**

```
 package com.mongodb.properties;

 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
 import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

 @Configuration
 public class SpringConfiguration {
 @Bean
 public AppConfigMongoDB getAppConfigMongoDB(){
        return new AppConfigMongoDB();
  }
 }
```

**Main.java**

```
package com.mongodb.properties;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
    AppConfigMongoDB mongo = applicationContext.getBean(AppConfigMongoDB.class);
    System.out.println("db= "+mongo.getMongoDb());
    System.out.println("URL= "+mongo.getMongoDbUrl());
  }
}
```

The properties file that I'm reading from called config.properties, it contains the following lines:

```
mongodb.url=1.2.3.4
mongodb.db=dataBase
```

I tested this small project and I got a stack trace that contains the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getAppConfigMongoDB': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private java.lang.String com.mongodb.properties.AppConfigMongoDB.mongodbUrl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanExpressionException: Expression parsing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'mongodb' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
at com.mongodb.properties.Main.main(Main.java:9)

 Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E:(pos 0): Property or field 'mongodb' cannot be found on object of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanExpressionContext' - maybe not public?
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.readProperty(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:226)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:93)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.PropertyOrFieldReference.getValueInternal(PropertyOrFieldReference.java:81)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueRef(CompoundExpression.java:51)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.CompoundExpression.getValueInternal(CompoundExpression.java:87)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.ast.SpelNodeImpl.getValue(SpelNodeImpl.java:120)
at org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression.getValue(SpelExpression.java:242)
at org.springframework.context.expression.StandardBeanExpressionResolver.evaluate(StandardBeanExpressionResolver.java:161)
... 18 more
```

Is it a problem of Spring calling beans? Or maybe is it a problem of properties file path or something else?

Comment: Does it work if you add setters for the properties?

Comment: No sorry. I got the same exception

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I can see several issues in the code.

1) Your place holders for values should be in the form `${mogodb.url}`, not `#{mongodb.url}`. The "#" has a different meaning (See [Spring Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html)).

2) You are going to need a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` bean to do the injection of the values

3) Sooner or later you are going to have a number of Beans floating around, and in I would use `@ComponentScan` to allow the context to know these without you having to mention them one by one

4) If you use `ComponentScan` to get the beans, you are going to have to provide  `AppConfigMongoDB` bean once

I end up with these classes after doing all that:

**Main.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
    AppConfigMongoDB mongo = applicationContext.getBean(AppConfigMongoDB.class);
    System.out.println("db= "+mongo.getMongoDb());
    System.out.println("URL= "+mongo.getMongoDbUrl());
  }
}
```

**SpringConfiguration.java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class SpringConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

**AppConfigMongoDB.java**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:config/config.properties")
public class AppConfigMongoDB {

  @Value("${mongodb.url}")
  private String mongodbUrl;

  @Value("${mongodb.db}")
  private String defaultDb;

  public String getMongoDb() {
    return defaultDb;
  }

  public String getMongoDbUrl() {
    return mongodbUrl;
  }
}
```

Comment: I provided a complete set of changes after I made the project and tested it. Please review and then we can clean up the comments so that this post is useful to others

Comment: Hey anyone know what is difference between #{} and ${}? or can anyone show me good source which I can learn it

Comment: I think a great place to start is if you follow the link in the answer [Spring Expressions](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html).You'll get a lot of the way to understanding the difference and why it is helpful. It boils down to this: ${} accesses properties, but #{} uses SpEL syntax and you can access things outside of the scope of your application properties and with full SpEL syntax. SpEL is powerful, and reading the docs will give you loads of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Nice reply given by @Ian Sparkes . Adding some of my inputs here. Configuring the PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer is not mandatory. I am able to get the value from my properties file and set it to the filed variable of my main Configuration class without it.

There is also another way to get the values of your keys in the properties file. Use org.springframework.core.env.Environment class . This class automatically loads all the key-value pairs in properties file that is in class path.

Example :

```js
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.easy.buy")
@PropertySource({"classpath:config.properties","classpath:props/db-${env}-config.properties", 
 "classpath:props/app-${env}-config.properties"})
public class CatalogServiceConfiguration {
 Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CatalogServiceConfiguration.class);
 
 //This object loads & holds all the properties in it as key-pair values
 @Autowired
 private Environment env;
 
 /**
  * Instantiate the DataSource bean & initialize it with db connection properties
  * @return
  */
 @Bean(name="basicDataSource")
 public BasicDataSource basicDataSource() {
  String dbUrl = env.getProperty("db.url");
  String dbUser = env.getProperty("db.user");
  String dbPwd = env.getProperty("db.pwd");
  String driver = env.getProperty("db.driver");
  
  logger.info("Initializing CatalogServiceConfiguration");
  logger.info("dbUrl=" + dbUrl);
  
  BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
  ds.setDriverClassName(driver);
  ds.setUrl(dbUrl);
  ds.setUsername(dbUser);
  ds.setPassword(dbPwd);
  
  return ds;
 }
}
```