# cannot read from properties file in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm always getting null value when reading properties from .properties file, i'm using spring framework 4.0.5 Release, and use Spring STS IDE,
my code is like this :

```
@Component
public class MenuClient {

     @Value("${menu.list}")
     private String url;

     public void showUrl() {
         System.out.println("url : " + url); //shows null
     }

}
```

my spring configuration like this

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http:/   /www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->


<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/assets/**" location="/resources/assets/" />
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany" />

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />

</beans:beans>
```

here is my config.properties location :

[image: file location]

Is there any missing or wrong configuration in my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: read properties file using spring annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828748/java-read-properties-file-using-spring-annotations)

Comment: no, i'm sure that i only define once in xml configuration. <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties" />

Comment: It cannot be null. If the value cannot be resolved the startup will fail. Make sure you aren't creating a new instance of the class yourself.

Comment: @esthrim take a look at answer below

Comment: Do you have root app context? If so can you provide the config?

Comment: @M.Deinum your answer is correct , i'm creating new instance myself and it always got null value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the problem, it's because i am creating new instance of the class. ( beginner mistakes) after i use @autowired to instantiate my class then the value is not null. 
thanks for @M.Deinum for pointing the root cause.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this:

```
  <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:config.properties" />
```

If not try to put the `config.properties` file in `META-INF` folder and use this:

```
   <context:property-placeholder
    location="classpath*:META-INF/config.properties" />
```