# Java : How to include a .properties file that is outside of jar into classpath?

Tags: java, spring, classpath

We would like to keep the .properties file out of the jar so that we can change the properties used in a module and we do not have to re-install the module.

Before Java 8, we used to run a script and include the .properties file in the way below and it worked. But since when we updated to Java 8 , this way of including .properties file in classpath is not working, means java program fails not finding the .properties file.

**My script to run the java project:**

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -d64 -Xms1G -Xmx16G -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -cp "/online/sand/lib/client-api-1.0.0.jar:/online/sand/oap_pub/lib/*:/online/sand/oap/oap_dw/run/client_api/application.properties" team.online.client.api.MasterProcessor  | tee -a client_api.log
```

We are using Sping context to pick up the properties file this way:

```
<util:properties id="app_props"
                 location="classpath*:/application.properties" />
```

Then a property in that appilcation.properties files is being used ( in many different files) this way:

```
@Value( "#{app_props[\"SERVICE_PATH_GET_METADATA\"]?:''}" )
private String metadataServicePath;
```

Looking for a way to keep the.properties file out of the jar and in classpath so that Spring context finds that file.

**Is their any other way than using ? We need to keep the properties file excluded from jar**

```
class.getClassLoader( ).getResourceAsStream( "application.properties" );
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a workaround making changes in the script to run the program by **using "::"** instead of ":" .

**Got the idea :**

==> java and javac are handling the classpath settings in a different way, 
**javac is searching for classes in / if the classpath contains double Classpath delimiters ("::" under Unix, ";;" under Windows).**

From this link which seemed convincing to me and that works. Please take a look here:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4809833

Answer (score 2):

Use this if you are using xml based config

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>
```

Then it will load the properties from anywhere as long as it is in class path not in the jar. You have to include it in class path as $CLASSPATH:application.properties

For annotation based, `@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")`
There is a sample here
[Java: read properties file using spring annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828748/java-read-properties-file-using-spring-annotations)